# How does asynchronous Socket operation behave? C#

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

Firstly, I'm accepting Socket async requests.

```
if (!_handle.AcceptAsync(_item)) AcceptClient(null, _item);
```

Handling them like this.

```
private void AcceptClient(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            do
            {
                switch(e.SocketError)
                {
                    case SocketError.Success:
                        // Do something with socket
                        break;

                    case SocketError.ConnectionReset:
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Socket Error");
                }

                e.AcceptSocket = null;
            }
            while (!_handle.AcceptAsync(e));
        }
        catch(ObjectDisposedException)
        {
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

So when socket is async accepted, then it loops while operation is sync. (Immediately processes next one) I don't understand a couple of things here though.

How does the handling code behave when lets say 20 clients connect at the same time? Does AcceptSync return false and those need to be processed straight after the first async one? Could some be async and some sync in such instance processing multiple at the same time?

Can multiple callbacks be invoked in this situation?

Thanks!